# jQuery: How to change data-bind on click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I have a a form with multiple fields on it. Below is example:

```
<input id="txtContactFirstName" name="txtContactFirstName" maxlength="20" class="k-textbox standardInput" required="required" data-bind="value: appointmentDetails.ContactFirstName" />
<input id="txtContactPhone" name="txtContactPhone"  data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" required="required" data-bind="value: appointmentDetails.ContactPhone" />
```

I have a checkbox on the form as well.

```
<label id="lblPatientDetailsSameAsPatient"><input id="patientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: intakeSettings.sameAsPatient" name ="PatientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox" />Same as Patient</label>
```

I want the **data-bind** values to change to something else when I click on the checkbox. So basically I will be pulling data for txtContactFirstName from patientDetails.FirstName  and txtContactPhone from patient.Details.FirstName? How can I achieve this on click and assign data-bind values to txtContactFirstName  and txtContactPhone ?

```
$("#patientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox").click(function (e) {
        if (e.target) {

           ?? Logic goes here which will assign data-bind values to txtContactFirstName  and txtContactPhone ?

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery method `data` to access data attributes on HTML elements, and set values. Also, I don't think you need the `if (e.target) {` logic you had there.

```
$("#patientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox").click(function (e) {

        $("#txtContactFirstName").data("bind",patientDetails.FirstName);
        $("#txtContactPhone").data("bind",patientDetails.Phone);

});
```

Here's the doc pertaining to the `data` method: http://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: This of course assumes that patientDetails is a valid object that you have access to in the place where you're setting the data attributes. It's hard to know without that context in your code, but it seems like it'd be medical data, so it's understandable to not share it in public.

Comment: I am able to access the object for testing purposes. But the textbox does not refresh with the new value. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `change` event of the `checkbox` as follows. *This assumes you'll have actual values in the `data-bind` attributes. And you can refine the code to remove the values when the checkbox is unchecked by using `that.checked ? $(this).data('bind') : ''` instead of `$(this).data('bind')`.*:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#patientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox').on('change', function() {
        var that = this;
        $(':text').val(function() {
            return that.checked ? $(this).data('bind') : '';
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtContactFirstName" name="txtContactFirstName" maxlength="20" class="k-textbox standardInput" required="required" data-bind="John" />
<input id="txtContactPhone" name="txtContactPhone"  data-role="maskedtextbox" data-mask="(999)-000-0000" class="k-textbox phoneInput" required="required" data-bind="555-1212" />

<label id="lblPatientDetailsSameAsPatient"><input id="patientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox" type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: intakeSettings.sameAsPatient" name ="PatientDetailsSameAsPatientCheckBox" />Same as Patient</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by adding a change event handler onto the observable your form is bound to. If the field that changed was intakeSettings.sameAsPatient, then setting properties on the observable that txtContactFirstName and txtContactPhone are bound to.

```js
// What your form is bound to
var viewModel = new kendo.observable({
  patient: {
    FirstName: 'Ted',
    Phone: '123-456-7890'
  },
  appointmentDetails: {
    ContactFirstName: '',
    ContactPhone: ''
  },
  intakeSettings: {
    sameAsPatient: false
  }
});

viewModel.bind('change', function(e) {
  // e.field is the property that changed, e.sender is the observable
  if(e.field === 'intakeSettings.sameAsPatient') {
    if(e.sender.get(e.field) === true) {
      e.sender.set('appointmentDetails.ContactFirstName', e.sender.patient.FirstName);
      e.sender.set('appointmentDetails.ContactPhone', e.sender.patient.Phone);
    }
    else {
      e.sender.set('appointmentDetails.ContactFirstName', '');
      e.sender.set('appointmentDetails.ContactPhone', '');
    }
  }
});
```

This way you keep any tight coupling with the form out of the javascript.